# Cupy gives unexpected results

Tags: cupy

I'm trying to accelerate some numpy code with cupy, but I'm getting some unexpected results.

I'm running this on a Mac Pro Late 2013, OSX 10.13.6 using a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti. 
I have been able to reproduce an error in ipython shown below. When determining a norm the multiplication of the conjugate with itself should give a real number. In numpy this is as expected, but using cupy I end up with an imaginary part.

```
In [54]: import numpy as np
In [55]: import cupy as cp
In [56]: q = np.arange(4)                                                                                                                             
In [57]: q.shape=[2,2]                                                                                                                                
In [58]: q=(0.23+0.33j)*(q+0.43)                                                                                                                      
In [59]: np.dot(np.conj(q).flatten(),q.flatten())                                                                                                     
Out[59]: (3.21975528+0j)
In [60]: q_gpu = cp.asarray(q)                                                                                                                        
In [61]: cp.dot(cp.conj(q_gpu).flatten(),q_gpu.flatten())                                                                                             
Out[61]: array(3.21975528-1.93612215e-17j)
In [62]: cp.sum(cp.abs(q_gpu)**2)                                                                                                                     
Out[62]: array(3.21975528)
In [63]: sys.version                                                                                                                                  
Out[63]: '3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 14:38:56) \n[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'
In [64]: sys.version_info                                                                                                                             
Out[64]: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

I have realized other inconsistencies in precision between running code in cupy vs. numpy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess very small precision error happens in calculation of GPU, because the calculation is parallelized and its calculation order will change by every execution which makes some numerical difference in result.